# Add an 'async' attribute to a JS include tag in asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

I saw how it can be done in MVC, but for a specific project I'm using Web-Forms.

I have

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/file.js") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

which generates the html:

```
<script src="/file.js?v=5jui8vHEj5_iAkaGiAccPPb2LcsdK1jQ1"></script>
```

I wish to add the sync attribute to the above tag.

I'd appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use RenderFormat to achieve this:

```
 <%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat ("<script src='{0}' async ></script>", "~/file.js") %>
```

Renders as: `<script src="/file.js" async=""></script>`

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt find RenderFormat until I realized it's only available in v. 1.1.0 of Web.Optimization

Answer (score 0):

This method would should the magic:

```
 <script src='<%: System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/file.js") %>' async> </script>
```

I extract from:

[Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)